# Using a subscribed value messes up the UI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a service (Volunteer Service) that gets data as an observable, from a JSON file

VolunteerService.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VolunteerService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  getVolunteerDetails() : Observable<any>{;
    return this.http.get("../assets/data/Sample_data.json")
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use this data for creating a profile page from the first of a list of volunteers

ProfilePage.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VolunteerService } from '../volunteer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.page.scss'],
})
export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
  volunteer : any
  //imageText : any
  constructor(private volunteerService : VolunteerService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrVol() 
    //this.volunteer = { "name" : "PANDA"}
  }
  getCurrVol(){
      this.volunteerService.getVolunteerDetails().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.volunteer = data.volunteers[0];
          console.log(this.volunteer);

        }
      )
  }
}
```

Now when I try to display the volunteer's name on the UI, the page breaks. The name is displayed correctly but the whole thing moves off to the side.

profile html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>profile</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-label> NAME </ion-label><ion-item>{{this.volunteer.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

When I get static data i.e uncomment the second line in ngOnInit(), it works fine. I would like to know why this is happening.
The first image shows what is rendered when the page is rendered with static volunteer, the second with volunteer from the observable.
[image: static]

> 

[image: observable]

This happens even if the .scss files(global, Profile.page.scss are empty, so that's not the issue.
It's also not an issue with my data itself, because the name is rendered correctly("panda 2" in the picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get any errors in the console?

In the mean time I think you should give `volunteer` an initial value

TS:

```
   ...
 
   export class ProfilePage implements OnInit {
      volunteer = '';
    
   ...
```

And you should check with an ngIf in the HTML if volunteer has a value and it is not empty.

HTML:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item *ngIf="!!volunteer">
    <ion-label> NAME </ion-label>
    <ion-text>{{this.volunteer.name}}</ion-text>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Yes giving the volunteer an initial value fixed the issue. I'm not clear on the why though, isn't the purpose of ngOnInit to get data before rendering the component?

Comment: If you open the console you will most likely see an undefined error of volunteer. It takes time for the service to get the data and there will be a small window when the volunteer variable is left undefined. The problem is that ngOnInit will run before the variable is assigned a value and the HTML tries to display a variable that is not defined, so it will throw an error.